# Insert parse CSV file to SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, opencsv

I'm parsing CSV file using OpenCSV library. I managed to skip first desired lines, choose only wanted columns and print it to console.
Now I'm struggling with inserting this to MSSQL database.
That's my code for parsing file:

```
JFileChooser fileopen = new JFileChooser();
    FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
            "CSV file", "csv");
    fileopen.setFileFilter(filter);

    int ret = fileopen.showDialog(null, "Choose file");
    if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();

        settings.detectFormatAutomatically();
        settings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true);
        settings.selectIndexes(7, 8, 13, 14);
        settings.setNumberOfRowsToSkip(9);

        List<String[]> rows = new CsvParser(settings).parseAll((fileopen.getSelectedFile()), "UTF-8");
        rows.forEach(arr -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)));
```

Now code

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Glass(Nr_Temp) values(Arrays.toString(rows.get(1)));
```

Is getting me whole row instead column (which is understandable:)) but is there any other solution to return columns values to insert them to SQL database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Ivan, I removed optimalization as files are small (less then 100 rows each) and also changed

```
ps.executeupdate() to `ps.executeBatch()
```

as it was uploading only last row, now It's working perfect, thank you for your time. 
Here is my changed code

```
try {

            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO dbo.Szyby_temp(nr_zlec_klienta, nr_ref_klienta, szerokosc, wysokosc, ilosc, opis_dodatkowy, data_importu) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, getdate())");
            for (String[] row : rows) {
                int i = 0;
                for (String columnValue : row) {    
                    ps.setString(++i, columnValue); //Parameter indexes start with 1
                }
                ps.addBatch();
            }
            ps.executeBatch(); //if number of rows in csv file is not divisible by maxbatchSize
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e, "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED

You need to iterate over `String[]` to get access to each separate value for a column.

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO dbo.Szyby_temp(nr_zlec_klienta, nr_ref_klienta, szerokosc, wysokosc, ilosc, opis_dodatkowy, data_importu) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, getdate())");
int maxBatchSize = 100; //Using batching for performance
int currentBatchSize = 0; 
for (String[] row : rows) {
    int i = 1;
    for (String columnValue : row) {           
        ps.setString(i++, columnValue); //Parameter indexes start with 1
    }
    ps.addBatch();
    if (++currentBatchSize % maxbatchSize == 0) {
      ps.executeUpdate();
    }
}
ps.executeUpdate(); //if number of rows in csv file is not divisible by maxbatchSize
```

Comment: Yeah that works but how to point columnValue to specific value in insert? 
When I try this one https://gist.github.com/n0rek/14fcb90eb20a1b7c771ac9685457ad18 it puts me every value in every column...

Comment: thanks but I'm getting "The value is not set for the parameter number 2" error.

Comment: @n0rek, please check how many elements are there in `row` variable. Are you sure that your csv file has enough values in every line?

Comment: Ivan variable row got 6 elements, my database got ID field which is identity, 6 variables mentioned in INSERT query and date field which is filled with getdate() statement in INSERT. 
When debugging ps goes all the variables from first row and then crashes. For testing I created csv file with only one row and still that error.
Edit: My csv file has more columns but I'm choosing only 6 of them using settings from opencsv library.

Comment: @n0rek, sorry there  was a misprint in my answer. `int i = 1;` should be moved to outer loop.